# Twitter Bootstrap Dropdown events Not Firing on Touch Devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, touch-event

The dropdown opens and closes fine but the click event / or touch event isn't being fired.  I put together a tiny test case [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashanova/p5AkF/4/) but its just as easy to run the [twitter bootsrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns).  I have tried this on Android and iOS devices.

I was hoping to rectify by including an Events library like, jQueryMobile or Hammer.js but I'm not sure if this will help as Twitter Bootstap (I think) includes its own touch handlers.

Anyone else come across the problem?

Comment: Theres a changed event?!! One second...

Comment: @PhonicUK i'm having trouble just getting a change event to fire atm.  I am working toward a solution using JQM's tap event which is firing successfully.  I'm right in the middle of something atm I'll get back to you with some proper findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a work around to this problem I used the Jquery Mobile touch events  and listened for tapevents on the dropdown.  Here is a simple implementation:

```
            $(".dropdown-menu").on("tap", "li a", function(e, ui){
                e.preventDefault();

                if ($(this).attr("data-toggle") === "modal")
                {
                     $($(this).attr('href')).modal("show");
                }

                return false;
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known issue that's resolved in bootstrap 2.1.2 - https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/pull/5054.

Edit: tried to apply the changes in the ticket about, but couldn't get it to work either.

@CrimsonChin - can you pls elaborate on your implementation. I tried your code, but using JQM with bootstrap I get all kinds of weird behaviors.

Comment: for my implementation I used the JQM download builder and just downloaded the Events and necessary Core files.